# Interpreting Negative Z-Scores Gene Expression

Tags: measurement, neuroimaging, genetics

When examining ISH heatmaps of gene expression in the brain, I'm typically looking for above-average expression in the form of high z-scores but have also encountered imaging with negative z-scores. Interpreting positive scores as indicative that a region uses more of the protein that gene encodes makes sense to me, but what does it mean for a region to express that gene below average...is it actively avoiding that gene more so than other regions, and what are some biological reasons it might do that?

Comment: I think you just need to think about what a z-score is, and what z-score = 0 represents. Z-scores are not correlations.

Comment: You're right, I was thinking about "correlation" in a non-statistical sense, and looking back it doesn't make much sense. I've edited the question to avoid using correlation interchangeably with deviation from the average.

Comment: Great, that helps a lot. But... the question now doesn't seem to make much sense. I mean, aside from Lake Wobegon, it's not really possible for everything to be *above* average in any group, is there? So, there really isn't an *explanation* needed, besides "You z-scored the data." Like my original comment started: think about what a z-score is, and what z-score = 0 represents.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back sooner: you're completely right, after looking at an example paper that applied the data I realized that my question is kind of self-explanatory. Thanks for clearing it up!